# Can I initialize a *char?

Tags: c++

On page 113, in The C++ Programming Language
(Third Edition and Special Edition), Stroustrup states:

```
struct address {
char * name ; // "Jim Dandy"
long int number ; // 61
//...
};

void f ()
{
address jd ;
jd.name = "Jim Dandy"; // Is this possible?
jd.number = 61 ;
}
```

Is this possible since there was not any memory allocated for the char* field of jd?

Update: Thank you all for your answers! Given that it's not safe, I won't use it. It just caught my attention when I saw it in the book.

Comment: If "Stroustrup states" it's possible, it's definitely possible :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Or at least, it was possible (but deprecated) when the book was written. It shouldn't be possible in C++11, without adding a `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Enough memory is allocated to hold a pointer to `char`, and the assignment sets the pointer to point to a static buffer holding the string `"Jim Dandy"`, so yes, this is possible. No allocation is needed since the string is not copied.

(However, setting a `char*` to a string literal is deprecated; use a `char const*` instead.)

Comment: It's not that setting a `char *` to a string literal is deprecated, it's just not a safe practice, but even then, it can be with a cast to type `(char [])`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: my GCC complains about a `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’`.

Comment: what version of GCC are you running, and what compiler flags do you have enabled?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: The implicit conversion to `char*` was deprecated in C++03 (or possibly C++98), and made invalid in C++11; although my compiler still accepts it with a warning even in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

The memory was allocated: enough for a pointer. Now that points to the static array that contains the string.

If you were expecting it to put a copy of the string in the structure, then that's not how C-style strings work; if you want that behaviour, then use the C++ `std::string` class instead.

I hope the example goes on to explain how dangerous this is. The static array is constant, but a quirk of the language means you're allowed to assign a non-`const` pointer to point to it. This allows you to write code that attempts to modify a constant object, which gives undefined behaviour at run time:

```
jd.name[0] = 'T'; // BOOM! Undefined behaviour.
```

If you're lucky, the compiler might warn you about that mistake. You can prevent it by declaring the pointer `const`:

```
char const * name;
...
jd.name[0] = 'T'; // Gives a friendly compile-time error
```